# Solve a non-homogeneous ODE when the right-hand side is a solution to the homogeneous ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Assume I have a second-degree ordinary differential equation
$$
u_1(x) f + u_2(x) f' + u_3(x) f'' = g(x),
$$
where $g$ solves the corresponding homogeneous equation, i.e.
$$
u_1(x) g + u_2(x) g' + u_3(x) g'' = 0.
$$
Is there a way to solve for $f$? Is there a solution at all?

The specific question (in case there is no general solution):
I need to solve 
$$
(\lambda+r)f - rxf' - \frac{\sigma^2}{2}x^2 f'' = x^{\alpha-\beta},
$$
for $\lambda, r, \sigma > 0$, where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ have been chosen such that $x^{\alpha-\beta}$ is a solution to the homogeneous ODE, i.e.
$$
x^{\alpha-\beta} \left(\lambda+r - r(\alpha-\beta) - \frac{\sigma^2}{2}(\alpha-\beta)(\alpha-\beta-1)\right) = 0.
$$

I have tried to plug in on the right-hand side and have also looked at the variable-coefficients method, but that did not work out.

**Solution:** The reduction-of-order approach worked very well. Thanks for your comments!

Comment: Your ODE is a 2nd order Euler's differential equation. The solution of the homogenous part is given by $f_h(x) = Ax^{s_1} + Bx^{s_2}$ where $s_i$ are obtained plugging solutions of the form $f = C x^s$ into the ODE. The general approach for solving the particular solution is setting $f(x) = A(x) f_1, \ f_1 = x^{s_1}$ (for example), or $f(x) = A(x) f_1 + B(x) f_2$ and solve for either $A(x)$ or $A(x)$ and $B(x)$. Why is this not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a slightly more general method, but divide the equation by $u_1(x)$ to get

$ f + \frac{u_2(x)}{u_1(x)}  f' + \frac{u_3(x)}{u_1(x)} f'' = \frac{g(x)}{u_1(x)}$, with $f=g(x)$ a solution of $f + \frac{u_2(x)}{u_1(x)}  f' + \frac{u_3(x)}{u_1(x)} f'' =0$. From here use [reduction of order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduction_of_order#General_method) to solve the equation.