# Finding solution of non-homogeneous ODE when we know the solutions of the homogeneous counterpart

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fundamental-solution

Given ODE is: $$y''+Py'+Qy=0$$
It has two solutions $f(x)$ and $xf(x)$.

I need to find the solution to the following non-homogeneous ODE: $$y''+Py'+Qy=f(x)$$
where $f(x)$ on the RHS is the solution of the first ODE.

I need to find its solution. I tried to apply variation of parameters method, but failed to proceed and also found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/893287/solve-a-non-homogeneous-ode-when-the-right-hand-side-is-a-solution-to-the-homoge) question similar. But being a beginner who's self-learning ODE, I am stuck. An elaboration of its solution would really help me to understand the working of such questions.

**EDIT**
I reconsidered the variation of parameter method and seemed to find a legit solution!
$$y=f(x)\left(\int \frac{-xf(x).f(x) dx}{f(x)^2} +c_1\right) + xf(x)\left( \int \frac{f(x). f(x) dx}{f(x)^2} +c_2\right)$$
**P.S.** The denominator is the wronskian  of $f(x)$ and $xf(x)$ which gives $f(x)^2$

On solving, it gives:
$$y=f(x) \cdot \left(\frac {x^2}{2}+c_2 x+ c_1\right)$$
Thanks for the valuable comment!

Comment: What happened when you applied variation of parameters? That seems like a reasonable way of proceeding.

Comment: @CW279 thanks for hinting... I completed the solution! Please do suggest if there exists alternative approaches to this!

Comment: Solution looks good! That's the answer I got too. Nice work!

Comment: @LutzLehmann I edited a typo. Is it good now?

Comment: Yes, looks good now.

Comment: @S.S Just so this doesn't go on the list of answered questions, you might consider typing up your solution and posting it as a proper answer, which you can then accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the method of variation of parameter, one gets the following:
$$y=f(x)\left(\int \frac{-xf(x).f(x) dx}{f(x)^2} +c_1\right) + x f(x)\left( \int \frac{f(x). f(x) dx}{f(x)^2} +c_2\right)$$
**P.S.** The denominator is the wronskian  of $f(x)$ and $xf(x)$ which gives $f(x) ^2$

On solving, it gives:
$$y=f(x) \cdot \left(\frac {x^2}{2}+c_2 x+ c_1\right)$$